# Increase the console display number of columns in JupyterNotebook

Tags: r, console, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with a table with more than 20 columns and Jupyter Notebook, how can I increase the number of columns outputted form the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

options(repr.matrix.max.cols=100) # <== the important bit

bind_cols(bind_cols(mtcars, mtcars), mtcars)
```

[image]